# How to check if the value of a parameter is a number?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I have a command with a parameter. I want to check if its value is a positive number and perform actions based on that.

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \ifnum#1>0%
        %some actions
    \fi
}
```

But I receive errors when the value of the parameter is not a number, e.g.:

```
\mycommand{*}
```

How can I check if the value of #1 is a number?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/testing-for-number perhaps?

Comment: Related Question: [Checking for valid floating point number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167369/checking-for-valid-floating-point-number/).

Comment: In many situations, e.g., with `\ifnum`, (La)TeX does form numbers by expanding expandable tokens. Thus your request implies also checking whether the tokens forming the "given parameter" at the stage of expansion form an algorithm which terminates at all and which does not trigger errors.  This is the halting problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Update:

Since it appears that the `\IfInteger` from the `xtring` package perceives blank strings as integers (the empty string `{}` is ok, but not `{ }`), I have defined a modified macro `\IsInteger` which handles that case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\IsInteger}[3]{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{ }{%
        #3% is a blank string
    }{%
        \IfInteger{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}%
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
$2$ is \IsInteger{2}{an integer}{not an integer}\par
$2.0$ is \IsInteger{2.0}{an integer}{not an integer}

$-7$ is \IsInteger{-7}{an integer}{not an integer}\par
$-7.0$ is \IsInteger{-7.0}{an integer}{not an integer}

$2.1$ is \IsInteger{2.1}{an integer}{not an integer}\par
$-7.1$ is \IsInteger{-7.1}{an integer}{not an integer}

a is \IsInteger{a}{an integer}{not an integer}

Empty String is \IsInteger{}{an integer}{not an integer}\par
Blank String is \IsInteger{       }{an integer}{not an integer}
\end{document}
```

---

You can use `IfInteger` from [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) to test if it is an integer number:

[image]

There is also `\IfDecimal` which works similarly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
2 is \IfInteger{2}{integer}{not an integer}

a is \IfInteger{a}{integer}{not an integer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. By the way, is there a TeX macro similar to \ifnum that I can use? I would prefer to keep the number of packages I am using to minimum.

Comment: I just noticed that \IfInteger interprets the empty string as an integer.

Comment: @Kaveh: Had created a modified macro `\IsInteger` to compensate for that.

Comment: It also appears that `\ifinteger` interprets negative numbers as non-integer.

Comment: @RobHall: Seems to work fine for negative values as well. See updated MWE.

Answer (score 22):

It depends mostly on the expected input and also on the context where you want to use the command.

If your expected input is either a number or something that *doesn't* start with digits, then

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \ifnum0<0#1\relax
    #1 is a positive number%
  \else
    #1 is not a positive number%
  \fi}
```

will do. For example, `\mycommand{42}` will do the comparison `0<042` which is true; instead, with `\mycommand{*}` TeX will see `\ifnum0<0*\relax` and it will test `0<0`, which is false, so the `*` will be ignored as part of the "true text". Also the test from `\mycommand{0}` will evaluate to false.

On the other hand, with `\mycommand{1x}` the test will evaluate to true and give wrong results.

Another expandable way can be

```
\def\mycommand#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-0#1}\relax
    #1 is a number%
  \else
    #1 is not a number%
  \fi
}
```

but `\mycommand{0}` would test true. Here `\mycommand{1x}` would answer that `1x` is not a number.

However, the argument should not contain "dangerous" items: `\mycommand{\textbf{x}}` would fail miserably.

A non-expandable test can be

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycommand#1{%
  \afterassignment\get@args\count@=0#1\hfuzz#1\hfuzz}
\def\get@args#1\hfuzz#2\hfuzz{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    #2 is a number%
  \else
    #2 is not a number%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This works also with input such as `\mycommand{\textbf{1}}` (the test will evaluate to false).

Comment: `\mycommand{\undefined\@undefined}` will fail. I am sure you know why I have used two undefined tokens.

Comment: Thank you. :) I decided to use the solution given by Peter.

Comment: @AhmedMusa All the proposed macros fail with only one undefined token.

Comment: Very nice solution.  Your first example is exactly what I needed today (with slight modification to handle negative numbers too).

Comment: How would it be possible to use this command as a typical if-then-else command? E.g. `\mycommand{\textbf{1}}{<Output if number>}{<Outpuf if not number>}`

Comment: @jessepeng In the first solution, substitute `#1 is a number` by `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` and `#1 is not a number` by `\expandafter\@secondoftwo`. Similarly for the second solution.

Comment: And could this now be easily extended to also handle floating point numbers? Or would an entirely different approach be necessary.

Comment: Nevermind, I asked a seperate question for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495919/checking-if-argument-is-a-floating-point-without-breaking-on-control-sequences-i

Answer (score 4):

Here is an expandable solution that accepts even undefined control sequences. It is admittedly acrobatic.

Some of the commands in *catoptions* package are redefined here for the sake of speed and experimentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\new@def\cptifdef#1{%
  \cptifblank{#1}{%
    \@secondoftwo
  }{%
    \csname @\ifx#1\@undefined second\else
    \ifx#1\relax second\else first\fi\fi oftwo\endcsname
  }%
}
\new@def\cptifundef#1{\cptifdef{#1}\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo}
\new@def\cptifleftbraced#1{%
  \cptifblank{#1}{%
    \@secondoftwo
  }{%
    \csname @\if\expandafter\cpt@car\detokenize{#1}\car@nil
      \expandafter\cpt@car\string{\car@nil\ifnum0=`}\fi
      first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
  }%
}
\new@def\cptifxpandable#1{%
  \cptifleftbraced{#1}{%
    \@secondoftwo
  }{%
    \expandafter\ifx\noexpand#1#1%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
  }%
}
\newcommand\cpttwooftwo[2]{#1#2}
\newcommand\cptifblank[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\noboundary\@gobble#1.\noboundary
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand\cptifcmdeq[2]{%
  \ifx#1#2\cpt@quark
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\long\def\cptifsolo#1{%
  \if0\pdfstrcmp{\detokenize\expandafter
    {\cpttwooftwo#1{}{}}}{\detokenize{#1{}}}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\new@def\cptxpand#1{%
  \romannumeral-`\q\cptifblank{#1}{\space}{\cpt@xpand#1\xpand}%
}
\def\cpt@xpand#1#2\xpand{%
  \cptifsolo{#1}{%
    \cptifundef{#1}{%
      \cpt@@xpand{#2}{\noexpand#1}%
    }{%
      \cptifxpandable{#1}{%
        \cpt@@xpand{#2}{\expandafter\cpt@xpand#1\xpand}%
      }{%
        \cpt@@xpand{#2}{\noexpand#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \cpt@@xpand{#2}{\cpt@xpand#1\xpand}%
  }%
}
\def\cpt@@xpand#1{%
  \expandafter\cptswap\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\q
  \cptifblank{#1}{\space}{\cpt@xpand#1\xpand}}%
}
\def\ifinteger#1{%
  \if\cptifblank{#1}{1}{\expandafter\ifinteger@a\romannumeral-`\q
  \cpt@xpand#1\xpand\cpt@nnil}00%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\ifinteger@a#1{%
  \cptifcmdeq#1\cpt@nnil{}{%
    \ifinteger@b#1\cpt@nil0123456789\cpt@nnil
  }%
}
\def\ifinteger@b#1\cpt@nil#2#3\cpt@nnil{%
  \expandafter\cptifcmdeq\cpt@car#1\car@nil#2{%
    \ifinteger@a
  }{%
    \cptifblank{#3}{%
      1\cpt@removetonnil
    }{%
      \ifinteger@b#1\cpt@nil#3\cpt@nnil
    }%
  }%
}

% Tests
\def\cmda{01}
\def\cmdb{xy}
\let\cmdc\undefined
\edef\cmdd{\ifinteger{\cmda}{True}{False}}
\edef\cmde{\ifinteger{\cmdc}{True}{False}}
\edef\cmdf{\ifinteger{\cmda\cmdb\cmdc}{True}{False}}
\show\cmdf
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, i'm "a bit late" to the party, but this seems to work fine:

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycommand#1{%
  \sbox\z@{\@tempcnta=0#1\relax}%
  \expandafter\ifdim\wd\z@>\z@\relax
    #1 is NOT an integer
  \else
    #1 is an integer
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

This works as long as you try to find positive integers (i.e., counters), not floats or negative numbers.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Instead, the page I used the command on disappeared and it gave no error messages :/

Comment: @MD004 Sounds like `\box0` is already occupied in your context. Try replacing `\sbox\z@` with `\sbox\@tempboxa` and `\wd\z@` with `\wd\@tempboxa` or maybe declare your own box register (`\newbox\mybox`) and use that for measuring, instead.