# Decrement macro, subtract 1 in side equation

Tags: math-mode, macros

While doing general math inside a math macro is not very feasible.
I feel like a mecro that does, only for single digits should be possible, with default for other inputs

`\dec{1}` to `0` 
`\dec{2}` to `1`
`\dec{3}` to `2`
...
`\dec{8}` to `7`
`\dec{9}` to `8`
`\dec{i}` to `i-1`
`\dec{10}` to `10-1`

How can this be done? some kind of switch/case?

**Use case:**
I am describing the mathematically model of a neural net,
each layer h<sup>(i-1)</sup>, can be derived by taking the sigmoid matrix w<sup>(i,i-1)</sup> multiplied by h<sup>(i)</sup>
I have named w<sup>(i,i-1)</sup>, as such because I had been forgetting which number layer it was from vs which layer it was to.
But I want to define a macro to so that for small numbers (The nural net will never have more than 9 layers), I have a macro so i can say `\w{5}` to get output equiv to `\mathbb{w}^{5,4)}`. However I also want to beable to speek about layers in general, so to say `\w{i}` to get `\mathbb{w}^{(i,i-1)}`

[image]

Comment: Could you show a use case?

Comment: done. Use case added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a "string test"; you can add to the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sw}{ m }
 {
  \mathbf{w}^{(#1,\oxinabox_decr:n { #1 })}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \oxinabox_decr:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{0}
    {2}{1}
    {3}{2}
    {4}{3}
    {5}{4}
    {6}{5}
    {7}{6}
    {8}{7}
    {9}{9}
    {10}{9}
    {11}{10}
   }
   {#1 - 1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\sh}[1]{\mathbf{h}^{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\sh{i-1}=\sigma(\sw{i}\sh{i})$, so, for the top layer, 
$\mathbf{y}=\sh{0}=\sigma(\sw{1}\sh{0})$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the number test from Peter Grill's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50113/15925 you can do the following:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring,etoolbox}

\newcommand{\pdec}[1]{#1-1}
\newcommand{\dec}[1]{\IfStrEq{#1}{ }{}{%
  \IfInteger{#1}{%
    \ifnumless{#1}{10}{%
      \ifnumgreater{#1}{0}{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}{\pdec{#1}}}%
      {\pdec{#1}}}
    {\pdec{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\( \dec{1} \) to \( 0 \)

\( \dec{2} \) to \( 1 \)

\( \dec{3} \) to \( 2 \)

\( \dec{8} \) to \( 7 \)

\( \dec{9} \) to \( 8 \)

\( \dec{i} \) to \( i-1 \)

\( \dec{10} \) to \( 10-1 \)

\( h^{(\dec{i})} = \sigma(\mathbf w^{(i,\dec{i})}\mathbf h^{(i)}) \).

\end{document}
```