# How to add a \global before \pgfmathsetmacro?

Tags: loops, foreach, pgfmath

It seems that one can't add `\global` before a `\pgfmathsetmacro` as that yields:

> You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'.

But that is the functionality I need here.

I am trying to compute the average of the integers in a list.  In the MWE the list I have is

```
\newcommand*{\MyData}{3,7,X,Y,8,9,Z}%
```

and the `\typeout` messages show:

```
**** NumberOfValidEnteries=1, \AverageValue=3.0
**** NumberOfValidEnteries=2, \AverageValue=3.5
**** NumberOfValidEnteries=3, \AverageValue=2.66666
**** NumberOfValidEnteries=4, \AverageValue=2.25
```

So it seems as if the `\pgfmathsetmacro` is working except it is not saving its state between successive iterations of the `\foreach`, which is exactly what the `\global` was there for in the first place.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50111/how-to-check-if-the-value-of-a-parameter-is-a-number
\newcommand*{\IfIsInteger}[3]{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{ }{%
        #3% is a blank string
    }{%
        \IfInteger{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyData}{3,7,X,Y,8,9,Z}%

\newcommand*{\AverageValue}{0}
\newcounter{NumberOfValidEnteries}
\newcommand*{\ComputeAverage}[1]{%
    %% Initialize (in case this is used more than once)
    \renewcommand*{\AverageValue}{0}
    \setcounter{NumberOfValidEnteries}{0}%
    %
    \edef\ExpandedDataEnteries{#1}% So that #1 can be a list or a macro defined list.
    \foreach \NewData in \ExpandedDataEnteries {%
        \IfIsInteger{\NewData}{%
            %\global% <---- I need this ????
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\AverageValue}{%  
                (\AverageValue * \arabic{NumberOfValidEnteries} + \NewData) /
                (\arabic{NumberOfValidEnteries} + 1)
            }%
            \stepcounter{NumberOfValidEnteries}%
            \typeout{**** NumberOfValidEnteries=\arabic{NumberOfValidEnteries}, \string\AverageValue=\AverageValue}%
        }{%
            % Not integer data so skip it
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \ComputeAverage{\MyData}%
    Average of integers in ``\MyData" is ``\AverageValue".
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfmathsetmacro\temp{...}\global\let\AverageValue\temp`

Comment: @egreg: Glad that that was easy. A bit embarrassed that I did not think of that. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can legally place `\global` only before an assignment command:

```
\global\def
\global\let
\global\mathchardef
\global\catcode
\global\advance
```

and so on. One should note that `\global` *wants and looks for* a suitable command following it, doing expansion. For instance, `etoolbox` defines

```
\newrobustcmd{\cslet}[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname#2}
```

so `\global\cslet{foo}{\bar}` is legal, because it will become

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname foo\endcsname\bar
```

after the first expansion, but since `\expandafter` is expandable, `\global` triggers its expansion and you get `\global\let\foo\bar` as wanted.

On the other hand, `\pgfmathsetmacro` is defined in `pgfmathcalc.code.tex` by

```
\def\pgfmathsetmacro#1#2{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
        \let#1=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmath@smuggleone{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

so one can definitely not add `\global` in front of it.

The easiest workaround is to say

```
\pgfmathparse
  (\AverageValue * \arabic{NumberOfValidEnteries} + \NewData) /
   (\arabic{NumberOfValidEnteries} + 1)
  }%
\global\let\AverageValue\pgfmathresult
```

since `\pgfmathparse` stores the result in `\pgfmathresult`.