# How to do length calculations with based on a `\foreach` array

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach, lengths, setlength

I'm trying to improve the readability of my `\drawHoshis` macro by creating variables for the x and y coordinates, besides also running a calculation with a minus inside parentheses (e.g. `x * (y - 1)`). I don't know why but I just can't seem to make TeX work with it. I think it's something related to the array from the TikZ/PGF `\foreach`:

```tex
\foreach \sloc in {{3, 3}, {3, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 7}, {5, 5}}{
  % This is what I'm tryig to improve:
  \filldraw (#3 * {\sloc}[0] - #3, #3 * {\sloc}[1] - #3)
    circle [radius=#3 / 10];
}
```

I'm trying to make it look more like this:

```tex
\newlength{\hoshiCoordX}
\newlength{\hoshiCoordY}
% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 3: step
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\drawHoshis{10}{19}{\step}'
\newcommand{\drawHoshis}[3]{
  \ifthenelse{#2 = 9} { 
    \foreach \sloc in {{3, 3}, {3, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 7}, {5, 5}}{
      \setlength{\hoshiCoordX}{\dimexpr #3 * ({\sloc}[0] - 1) \relax}
      \setlength{\hoshiCoordY}{\dimexpr #3 * ({\sloc}[1] - 1) \relax}

      \filldraw (\hoshiCoordX, \hoshiCoordY)
        circle [radius=#3 / 10];
    }
  }{}
}
```

Here's the complete *working* example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\step}
% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\gogrid{10}{19}'
\newcommand{\goGrid}[2]{
  \setlength{\step}{\dimexpr #1cm / (#2 - 1) \relax} % chktex 1

  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (#1, #1);
  
  \drawHoshis{#1}{#2}{\step}
}

% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 3: step
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\drawHoshis{10}{19}{\step}'
\newcommand{\drawHoshis}[3]{
  \ifthenelse{#2 = 9} { 
    \foreach \sloc in {{3, 3}, {3, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 7}, {5, 5}}{
      % This is what I'm tryig to improve:
      \filldraw (#3 * {\sloc}[0] - #3, #3 * {\sloc}[1] - #3)
        circle [radius=#3 / 10];
    }
  }{}
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \goGrid{10}{9}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Goban 1}\label{my_goban_1}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I've tried many variations of this but none have worked so far (I did try without `\dimexpr` as well). Is anyone able to spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\filldraw (#3 * {\sloc}[0] - #3, #3 * {\sloc}[1] - #3)`?

Comment: Unrelated: You can replace `\setlength{\step}{\dimexpr #1cm / (#2 - 1) \relax}` with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{#1 / (#2 - 1)}` and delete `\newlength{\step}`. And I'd probably just use `\ifnum#2=9\relax ... \fi` instead of the `\ifthenelse` command which requires an additional package.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be `0` and `1`. That was a typo. The indices inside the desired example were correct though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure what you want the code to produce, but things will be much easier if you use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\setlength` as this will automatically do the calculations for you. There is no need to add a length unit, because the base unit in Ti*k*Z is 1 cm anyways. I'd also replace the `\ifthenelse` command that requires some package by `\ifnum`.

If you want to do calculations inside a coordinate that require the use of parenthesis, you need to wrap things in curly braces. The following two lines are both representing the same coordinate:

```
(#3 * {\sloc}[0] - #3, #3 * {\sloc}[1] - #3) 
({#3 * ({\sloc}[0] - 1}, {#3 * ({\sloc}[1] - 1)})
```

In any case, it seems that in your code the indices for selecting the items from the arrays are wrong, at least in one of the code snippets you show. Make sure that these are correct.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\gogrid{10}{19}'
\newcommand{\goGrid}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{#1 / (#2 - 1)} % chktex 1
  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (#1, #1);
  \drawHoshis{#1}{#2}{\step}
}

% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 3: step
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\drawHoshis{10}{19}{\step}'
\newcommand{\drawHoshis}[3]{
  \ifnum#2=9\relax 
    \foreach \sloc in {{3, 3}, {3, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 7}, {5, 5}}{
      % This is what I'm trying to improve:
      %\filldraw (#3 * {\sloc}[0] - #3, #3 * {\sloc}[1] - #3)
      \filldraw ({#3 * ({\sloc}[0] - 1}, {#3 * ({\sloc}[1] - 1)})
        circle[radius={#3 / 10}];
    }
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \goGrid{10}{9}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\gogrid{10}{19}'
\newcommand{\goGrid}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{#1 / (#2 - 1)} % chktex 1
  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (#1, #1);
  \drawHoshis{#1}{#2}{\step}
}

% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 2: board size (square)
% 3: step
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\drawHoshis{10}{19}{\step}'
\newcommand{\drawHoshis}[3]{
  \ifnum#2=9\relax 
    \foreach \sloc in {{3, 3}, {3, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 7}, {5, 5}}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\hoshiCoordX}{#3 * ({\sloc}[0] - 1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\hoshiCoordY}{#3 * ({\sloc}[1] - 1)}
      \filldraw (\hoshiCoordX, \hoshiCoordY)
        circle[radius={#3 / 10}];
    }
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \goGrid{10}{9}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output of both code snippets:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Jasper Habicht! Do you know if there's something similar to this but for `\newcounter`?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro It depends on what you want to do. There is `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` which is similar to `\pgfmathsetmacro` but it always outputs an integer, there is also `\pgfmathsetcount`, but you need to initialize the counter first using `\newcounter` for example. See [the online manual](https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#sec-94.1) for more information about this.

Comment: Thank you for the tips again, @JasperHabicht! If you're interested, I've just now [asked a follow-up question to this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708841/64441), based on the tips you gave me.

Comment: In the future, I think I might need the variable `\step` as a global variable, for other macros. Do you know if there's a way of doing that through `\pgfmathsetmacro`?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro You [cannot directly say `\global\pgfmathsetmacro`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164476/47927) as far as I know, but  you can always store the result of some `\pgfmath...` calculation globally in another variable via other means. My point was that it is much easier to use PGF for the calculations. How you store the result is another thing.