# Checking if argument is a floating point without breaking on control sequences in argument

Tags: macros, conditionals, programming

Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50131/191037) to test whether an argument is a positive integer, I would like to extend this to floating point numbers. I want to have a macro `\TestNumber` that checks, whether its first argument is a floating point or integer and then conditionally outputs either its second or third argument. The twist is, that it should not break when called like `\TestNumber{\textbf{Hello}}`, which is the case with for example `\IfDecimal` from the `xstring` package.

The following does the trick for positive integers (`\TestNumber{\textbf{123}}{Number}{Not a number}` prints `Not a number`), but as said, I would like to extend this to floating point numbers as well. So, `\TestNumber{12.3}{Number}{Not a number}` should output `Number`, while `\TestNumber{\textbf{12.3}}{Number}{Not a number}` should output `Not a number`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\TestNumber#1{%
  \afterassignment\get@args\count@=0#1\hfuzz#1\hfuzz}
\def\get@args#1\hfuzz#2\hfuzz{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code needs a little more token handling than the simpler case for integers. I made the function expandable, so this adds a little bit more code too, but it's not *that* much.

First the function uses `\detokenize` to ensure that TeX doesn't try to expand anything weird later on. After that the code proceeds removing a possible integer part with a possible sign using `\romannumeral-0#1` (and some other things), then the code removes a possible decimal separator, and removes the trailing decimal part. After that the code checks whether the remaining token list is empty. If it is, then the argument was a valid number, otherwise it was not.

Testing a few possibilities, returns the desired output:

> [image]

The code being expandable means that you can do:

```latex
\def\TestIfIsAPositiveNumber#1{%
  \ifdim
    \TestNumber{#1}{#1}{-1}pt
      > 0pt
    Positive :)
  \else
    Negative or weird :(
  \fi
}
```

and get the expected output.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\TestNumber#1{%
  \Test@ifempty{#1}%
    {\@secondoftwo}%
    {\expandafter\Test@integer\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}}}%
\def\Test@integer#1{%
  \expandafter\Test@after@integer\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral-0\expandafter\Test@remove@leading@minus\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral-0\number0#1}}}
\def\Test@after@integer#1{%
  \expandafter\Test@ifempty\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral-0\Test@remove@leading@dot{#1}}}
\def\Test@remove@leading@minus#1{%
  \Test@remove@leading-{#1}}
\def\Test@remove@leading@dot#1{%
  \Test@remove@leading.{#1}}
\def\Test@remove@leading#1#2{%
  \Test@ifempty{#2}{}%
    {\Test@@remove@leading#1#2\qstop}}
\def\Test@@remove@leading#1#2#3\qstop{%
  \if\noexpand#1\noexpand#2%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi{#3}{#2#3}}
\def\Test@ifempty#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\test#1{\texttt{\detokenize{#1} = }\TestNumber{#1}{Number}{Not a number}\par}
\test{0}
\test{1}
\test{-1}
\test{.23}
\test{-.23}
\test{1.23}
\test{-1.23}
\test{\textbf{1.23}}
\end{document}
```

Or, a simpler (but unexpandable) version with `l3regex` (the expression was copied from `interface3` and changed the control spaces `\␣` by `\s`, which matches `[\ \^^I\^^J\^^L\^^M]`, according to the manual):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_const:Nn \c_jessepeng_float_regex { ^[\+\-\s]*(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*$ }
\NewDocumentCommand \TestNumber { m m m }
  { \jessepeng_if_float:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \jessepeng_if_float:n #1 { T, F, TF }
 {
   \regex_match:NnTF \c_jessepeng_float_regex {#1}
     { \prg_return_true: }
     { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\def\test#1{\texttt{\detokenize{#1} = }\TestNumber{#1}{Number}{Not a number}\par}
\test{0}
\test{1}
\test{-1}
\test{.23}
\test{-.23}
\test{1.23}
\test{-1.23}
\test{\textbf{1.23}}
\end{document}
```

It yields the same result but is much slower and is not expandable.

Comment: Perhaps `\s` for a space. Didn't test yours.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, fixed. I also forgot to mention that the `l3regex` version was stolen from the documentation ;-)

Comment: +1 for the test cases:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 6):

Borrowing a test file from the other answer, as you failed to supply one in the question, for pdflatex at least you can use its built in regex support

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\TestNumber#1{%
\ifnum1=\pdfmatch{^\string\s*-?[0-9]*[.0-9][0-9]*\string\s*$}{\detokenize{#1}}
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}


\begin{document}
\def\test#1{\texttt{\detokenize{#1} = }\TestNumber{#1}{Number}{Not a number}\par}
\test{}
\test{0}
\test{1}
\test{-1}
\test{.23}
\test{-.23}
\test{1.23}
\test{-1.23}
\test{\textbf{1.23}}
\end{document}
```

or a version using Lua patterns for luatex

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ifx\pdfmatch\@undefined
\ifx\directlua\@undefined
% xetex
\typeout{use l3regex from the other answer}
\else
% luatex
\def\TestNumber#1{%
\ifnum1=\directlua{if (string.find("\luaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}","^[-]?\@percentchar d*[.]?\@percentchar d+$"))
then tex.write("1 ")
else tex.write("0 ")
end
}
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}
\fi
\else
% pdftex
\def\TestNumber#1{%
\ifnum1=\pdfmatch{^\string\s*-?[0-9]*[.0-9][0-9]*\string\s*$}{\detokenize{#1}}
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\def\test#1{\texttt{\detokenize{#1} = }\TestNumber{#1}{Number}{Not a number}\par}
\test{}
\test{0}
\test{1}
\test{-1}
\test{.23}
\test{-.23}
\test{1.23}
\test{-1.23}
\test{\textbf{1.23}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Up until today I didn't know pdfTeX had regex support. Really nice :-)

Comment: Do you have a version for `lualatex` because we've lost `\pdfmatch`!

Comment: @AlainMatthes see edited answer