# Is it possible to define macro with numeric name and without at the same time?

Tags: macros

I want to define variable with letters and with numerical numbers. But the variable have same name with and without numeric value. Here is an example:

Basically I want to define

```
  \def\lam{\lambda}
  \newcommand{lam}{\lambda}
  \def\lam#1{\lambda^{#1}}
```

In the expression I have

```
  F = \lam + \lam2 + \lam3
```

The output should be

```
  F = \lambda + \lambda^2 + \lambda^3
```

Comment: short answer no, use `\lamb` and `\lamc` technically you can re-classify digits as letters so `\lam2` works, but then you break most of the rest of latex.

Comment: or with the definition you have, `\lam{}+\lam2+\lam3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can do this:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\lam{\lambda\afterassignment\lamA\tmpnum=0}
\def\lamA{\ifnum\tmpnum=0 \else ^{\the\tmpnum}\fi}

$ F = \lam + \lam2 + \lam3 $
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. However to overcome this I have to add three lines of command!!

Comment: @Boogeyman Only one `\def` line in needed for each new similar command, for example `\def\delt{\delta\aftrerassignment\lamA\tmpnum=0}`. In other words, the line 1 and 3 from the code above is common for each such macros.

Comment: one more question, if my expression also contains `\lam` and `\lam1` , is there any way to force them to have same output?

Comment: @Boogeyman Yes, define `\def\lamA{\ifnum\tmpnum>1 ^{\the\tmpnum}\fi}`

Answer (score 1):

I found how to check if argument is a number [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50111/how-to-check-if-the-value-of-a-parameter-is-a-number). And after you just output if that's not a number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lam}[1]{%
  \ifnum0<0#1\relax
    $\lambda^{#1}$%
  \else
     $\lambda$~{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
  
 F = \lam + \lam2 + \lam3
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution. But this is causing some problem when I do say `\frac{1}{\lam}'.

Comment: Basically what you are doing is to replace `\lam` by `\lam^{}` like @David Carlisle has said in the comment.

Comment: @Boogeyman no. This does not make empty superscripts

Comment: it would be better to take the `$` and `~` out of the definition and put `$` around the expression otherwise spacing will be wrong for = and +