# Validate a date using datetime2 or other packages

Tags: conditionals, date

Can an English date be validated using the `datetime2` package? If not, are there any other packages/ways to do this?

- Valid arguments: `2023-06-14` , `2023-09-24` , ...
- Invalid arguments: `2023-06-XX` , `2023-09-32` , ...

Ideally I'd like to condition on an in-/valid argument in the following way:

```
\IfJulianDate{<date>}{<true code>}{<false code>}
```

Comment: This problem is best divides into two: is it even an integer (and not `XX` or `25.7`) and if it is is it a proper date? For the first, I believe `xstring` has a test for that but I'm sure LaTeX3 has tests for that as well (at the very least a regexp test is possible). For the later, we could just feed it into PGFCalender and test whether we get the same date back (04-32 would return 05-01). Though, we could just test for 30 or 31 days and need a leap year test for February, without any calendar packages.

Comment: For the first: [Q50111](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50111) and related.

Comment: Can you give the PGF calendar sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PGFCalendar sequence is basically this:

```
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{<date>}{\<count>}
\pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\<count>}{\Year}{\Month}{\Day}
```

and then test `\Year`, `\Month`, `\Day` against your input (which you need to split somehow at the `-`s). Note that `\<count>` needs to be a single token count, not a LaTeX counter, not `\count0` or even a macro. The L3 scratch “integer” `\l_tmpa_int` is one.

In the code below, I'm using L3Regex to set up a regular expresion for the typical *Year*-*Month*-*Date* format out of integers meaning that 0003-000012-000000 would match true against it.

However, negative years wouldn't match the regexp. Neither would `2023-09-last` or `2023-09-19+3` which would all be valid PGFCalendar dates. The `\A` (beginning) and the `\Z` (end) make sure only a date and nothing else matches, so neither `Foo 2023-09-13 Bar` nor `2023-09-19 2023-09-20` (which would be two dates), both of which would break PGFCalendar.

The `\regex_extract_once` macro puts all matches into `\l_tmpa_seq` where the first element is the whole match and the other ones are the capturing groups denoted by the pair of `()`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar, pgffor}% pgffor just for the .list handler
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_new:N \l_mbc_datetest
\regex_set:Nn\l_mbc_datetest { \A (\d+) \- (\d+) \- (\d+) \Z }
\NewDocumentCommand { \IfJulianDate }{ m m m }{
  \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \l_mbc_datetest { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq {
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{ #1 } { \l_tmpa_int }
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate { \l_tmpa_int }{ \l_tmp_year_int }
                         { \l_tmp_month_int }{ \l_tmp_day_int }
    \bool_lazy_all:nTF {
      { \int_compare_p:nNn { \seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq{2} } = { \l_tmp_year_int  } }
      { \int_compare_p:nNn { \seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq{3} } = { \l_tmp_month_int } }
      { \int_compare_p:nNn { \seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq{4} } = { \l_tmp_day_int   } }
    }{ #2 }{ #3 }
  }{ % not even proper date format
    #3
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{tester/.code=#1 is \IfJulianDate{#1}{a real}{not a proper} date\par,
         tester/.list={
           2023-06-14, 2023-09-24, 2023-06-XX, 2023-09-32,
           2023-02-29, 2023-09-19 2023-09-20, -0001-12-24}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> 2023-06-14 is a real date
> 2023-09-24 is a real date
> 2023-06-XX is not a proper date
> 2023-09-32 is not a proper date
> 2023-02-29 is not a proper date
> 2023-09-19 2023-09-20 is not a proper date
> -0001-12-24 is not a proper date

Comment: I just realize there's a way to get the individual matches from l3regex …

Comment: It doesn't matter about the `LaTeX3` extraction code because it's easy to do... I'll update your question to produce a cleaner code. Thanks for mentioning `pgfcalendar`.

Comment: @projetmbc My *question*? Eitherway, I've updated my answer. Don't know the efficience of `\bool_lazy_all`. Next step would be to do implement the versions that can generate variants for the full L3 expierence.

Comment: Answer and not question... You are right. Checking dates in LaTeX3 can be done, but I am lazy like some booleans. ;-)

Comment: I have posted a draft `LaTeX3` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first draft code in "pure" `LaTeX3`: error messages are not implemented because it is just a PoC. My code should be factorizable. Any advice is welcome...

**EDIT: use of a conditional**

```
\documentclass{article}

% Source for easy testing via pgffor:
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696444/6880
\usepackage{pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_mbc_month_size
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_mbc_month_size {%
  0,  % Not used.
  31, % January
  0,  % February: this special value will help us to find bugs...
  31, % March
  30, % April
  31, % May
  30, % June
  31, % July
  31, % August
  30, % September
  31, % October
  30, % November
  31 % December
}

% The rule defining a leap year A is as follows:
%
%    + If A % 4 != 0, the year is not a leap year.
%
%    + If A % 4 = 0 , the year is a leap year unless 
%      A % 100 = 0 and A % 400 != 0. 
\prg_set_conditional:Npnn \if_leap_year:N #1 { p , T , TF } {
  \int_compare:nTF { 
    \int_mod:nn #1 { 4 } = 0
  }{
    \int_compare:nTF {
      \int_mod:nn #1 { 100 } = 0
    }{
      \int_compare:nTF {
        \int_mod:nn #1 { 400 } = 0
      }{
        \prg_return_true:
      }{
        \prg_return_false:
      }
    }{
      \prg_return_true:
    }
  }{
    \prg_return_false:
  }
}

\regex_new:N \g_mbc_date_format_rgx
\regex_set:Nn\g_mbc_date_format_rgx { \A (\d+) \- (\d+) \- (\d+) \Z }

\str_new:N \l_mbc_date_year_str
\str_new:N \l_mbc_date_month_str
\str_new:N \l_mbc_date_day_str

\int_new:N \l_mbc_date_year_int
\int_new:N \l_mbc_date_month_int
\int_new:N \l_mbc_date_day_int

\NewDocumentCommand { \ValidateJulianDate }{ m }{
  \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \g_mbc_date_format_rgx { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq {
% Integer values found.
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_mbc_date_day_str
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_mbc_date_month_str
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_mbc_date_year_str
    
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_date_day_int   \l_mbc_date_day_str
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_date_month_int \l_mbc_date_month_str
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_date_year_int  \l_mbc_date_year_str
 
% 1 <= month <= 12
    \int_compare:nTF { 1 <= \l_mbc_date_month_int <= 12 }{
% February special setting.
      \if_int_compare:w \l_mbc_date_month_int = 2
        \if_leap_year:NTF \l_mbc_date_year_int {
          \seq_set_item:Nnn \g_mbc_month_size 2 { 29 }
        }{
          \seq_set_item:Nnn \g_mbc_month_size 2 { 28 }
        }
      \fi:

% Good day.
      \int_compare:nTF {
        1 <= \l_mbc_date_day_int 
          <= \seq_item:Nn \g_mbc_month_size 
                          { \int_use:N \l_mbc_date_month_int }
      }{
        OK
% Bad day.
      }{
        KO (day)
      }

 % NOT(1 <= month <= 12).
    }{
      KO (month)
    }

 % Syntax error
  }{
    KO (syntax)
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{OK}

\pgfkeys{tester/.code=\ValidateJulianDate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
         tester/.list={
           2023-06-14, 
           2023-09-24, 
           2023-02-28,
           2024-02-29,
           400-02-29
         }
}


\section{KO -- Invalid day}

\pgfkeys{tester/.code=\ValidateJulianDate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
         tester/.list={
           300-02-29,
           2023-02-29,
           2024-02-30,
           2023-09-00,
           2023-09-32
         }
}


\section{KO -- Invalid month}

\pgfkeys{tester/.code=\ValidateJulianDate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
         tester/.list={
           2023-19-32,
           2023-00-29
         }
}


\section{KO -- Syntax error}

\pgfkeys{tester/.code=\ValidateJulianDate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
         tester/.list={
           2023-06-XX,  
           2023-09-19 2023-09-20, 
           -0001-12-24
         }
}

\end{document}
```

### OUTPUT

```
1 OK
OK: 2023-06-14 
OK: 2023-09-24 
OK: 2023-02-28 
OK: 2024-02-29 
OK: 400-02-29

2 KO – Invalid day
KO(day): 300-02-29 
KO(day): 2023-02-29 
KO(day): 2024-02-30 
KO(day): 2023-09-00 
KO(day): 2023-09-32

3 KO – Invalid month
KO(month): 2023-19-32 
KO(month): 2023-00-29

4 KO – Syntax error
KO(syntax): 2023-06-XX
KO(syntax): 2023-09-19 2023-09-20 
KO(syntax): -0001-12-24
```