# LaTeX3 - Advice on a code to validate an ISO date

Tags: latex3, code

The following code is a POC showing a way to validate one Julian date in "pure" `LaTeX3`: it is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696438/validate-a-date-using-datetime2-or-other-packages/696444#696444).

There is no doubt that this code contains some clumsiness. Any advice would be welcome, except for error handling via messages, which is something I know how to do.

For example, do `\str_new:N \l_mbc_date_year_str` and `\l_mbc_date_year_int` are both necessary?

```
\documentclass{article}

% Source for easy testing via pgffor:
%     + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696444/6880
\usepackage{pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_mbc_month_size
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_mbc_month_size {%
  0,  % Not used.
  31, % January
  0,  % February: this special value will help us to find bugs...
  31, % March
  30, % April
  31, % May
  30, % June
  31, % July
  31, % August
  30, % September
  31, % October
  30, % November
  31  % December
}

% The rule defining a leap year A is as follows:
%
%    + If A % 4 != 0, the year is not a leap year.
%
%    + If A % 4 = 0 , the year is a leap year unless 
%      A % 100 = 0 and A % 400 != 0.
%
% This leads to the following one-line validating test.
%
%     + (A % 4 = 0) AND (A % 100 != 0 OR A % 400 = 0)
\prg_set_conditional:Npnn \if_leap_year:N #1 { p , T , TF } {
  \bool_if:nTF {
    \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn #1 { 4 } = 0 }
    && (
      \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn #1 { 100 } != 0 }
      ||
      \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn #1 { 400 } = 0 }
    )
  }{
    \prg_return_true:
  }{
    \prg_return_false:
  }
}

\regex_new:N \g_mbc_date_format_rgx
\regex_set:Nn\g_mbc_date_format_rgx { \A (\d+) \- (\d+) \- (\d+) \Z }

\tl_new:N \l_mbc_date_year_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mbc_date_month_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mbc_date_day_tl

\int_new:N \l_mbc_date_year_int
\int_new:N \l_mbc_date_month_int
\int_new:N \l_mbc_date_day_int

\NewDocumentCommand { \ValidateISODate }{ m }{
  \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \g_mbc_date_format_rgx { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq {
% Integer values found.
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_mbc_date_day_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_mbc_date_month_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_mbc_date_year_tl
    
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_date_day_int   \l_mbc_date_day_tl
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_date_month_int \l_mbc_date_month_tl
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_date_year_int  \l_mbc_date_year_tl
 
% 1 <= month <= 12
    \int_compare:nTF { 1 <= \l_mbc_date_month_int <= 12 }{
% February special setting.
      \int_compare:nT { \l_mbc_date_month_int = 2 }{
        \if_leap_year:NTF \l_mbc_date_year_int {
          \seq_set_item:Nnn \g_mbc_month_size 2 { 29 }
        }{
          \seq_set_item:Nnn \g_mbc_month_size 2 { 28 }
        }
      }

% Good day.
      \int_compare:nTF {
        1 <= \l_mbc_date_day_int 
          <= \seq_item:Nn \g_mbc_month_size 
                          { \int_use:N \l_mbc_date_month_int }
      }{
        OK
% Bad day.
      }{
        KO (day)
      }

 % NOT(1 <= month <= 12).
    }{
      KO (month)
    }

 % Syntax error
  }{
    KO (syntax)
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{OK}

\pgfkeys{
  tester/.code=\ValidateISODate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
  tester/.list = {
    2023-06-14,
    2023-09-24,
    2023-02-28,
    2024-02-29,
    400-02-29
  }
}


\section{KO -- Invalid day}

\pgfkeys{
  tester/.code=\ValidateISODate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
  tester/.list = {
    300-02-29,
    2023-02-29,
    2024-02-30,
    2023-09-00,
    2023-09-32
  }
}


\section{KO -- Invalid month}

\pgfkeys{
  tester/.code=\ValidateISODate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
  tester/.list = {
    2023-19-32,
    2023-00-29
  }
}


\section{KO -- Syntax error}

\pgfkeys{
  tester/.code=\ValidateISODate{#1}{:} #1\par\medskip,
  tester/.list = {
    2023-06-XX,
    2023-09-19 2023-09-20,
    -0001-12-24
  }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point about `str` vs `tl`... As far as speed is concerned, time will tell whether optimisation is necessary or not.

Comment: Noted. In my [previous attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696571/6880) , I use `\int_compare:nTF`, but I really think that the first concern is readability, and if optimization becomes a need, then you can "dirty" the code.

Comment: For 30 and 31, I prefer a fixed uncalculated sequence, even if this is clearly not clever. At worst, I would tend to produce this type of constant via a `Python` script.

Comment: Your variable `\g_mbc_month_size` is not named according the the l3 specification. A sequence variable name should always end `_seq`. If it is internal, it should begin `\l__` or `\g__`. Also, I doubt whether you need a global variable here. If not, it would be better local. The same goes for all other cases of internal variables/functions etc. They all should have `__` at the start or immediately following the initial `\if`, `\l`, `\c`, `\g` etc. Plus your conditional should include `mbc`. `\ValidateJulianDate` should preferably include `mbc`. Also, these are NOT Julian dates.

Comment: You should use `\prg_new_conditional:Npnn` to avoid overwriting an existing defintion. You should only use `set` if you've previously used `new`. Note you can use `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` to generate alternative argument specifications. This would be another way of dealing with the `N`/`n` confusion. If you generate a variant of `n` using `V`, you can pass an unbraced variable directly.

Comment: @cfr So should there always be a `N`/`V` variant for each `n` just in case someone wants to use `\int_year` or `\my_value_year` instead of `{ \int_year }`? Why shouldn't I force my user (or me in case of `__`= to always use `{ … }` even if it's just one token?. Will the `N`/`V` get expanded once and then forwarded to the `n` version if the variants are generated?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No, you don't need to generate them or force bracing. The user or yourself generates any missing variants as they're needed. It works in the same way for your own functions as it does for kernel ones. For example, I have `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_abs:n { v }` but also `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__chronos_dateformat_sign:n { v }`. It's not a question of shouldn't force your user to use braces. It's a question of can't. (Well, I suppose you *could*, but not without breaking a whole lot of stuff.)

Comment: A `V` substitutes the value of the variable into a function specified with `n`. I'm not sure if `forward` is quite the right way to put it. You can't generate a variant which replaces `n` with `N`. `N` and `n` are base forms. All functions are defined with argument specifications which use only  the base forms (`N`,`n` etc.). You can't define a function with `V` or `o` in the argument specification. Those are always generated variants. `N` -> `c`; `n` > `V`, `v`, `e`, `o` etc.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel If you really want to force the user to brace the argument, you need to use one of the more primitive forms i.e. the equivalent of defining a delimited macro. But expl3 discourages that unless it's really unavoidable.

Comment: You’re not dealing with Julian dates, but ISO dates

Comment: @egreg I have updated my question.

Comment: Well, now that two people told you that your question is wrong (iso vs julian) my answer feels even more pointless. I explicitly decided that `400-2-003` is a valid input because it might not be ISO but it is still unambiguous and we can extract the integers for future usage.

Comment: Maybe dealing only with ISO will be sufficient in concrete use. I am a `L3` baby coder so my concern is more about coding. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dealing with ISO formatted dates, not with Julian dates: a [*Julian day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) is just an integer, a *Julian date* is a decimal number.

ISO allows dates to be in the forms `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyymmdd`, but let's assume you only allow the hyphenated form.

Starting with a regex comparison seems a good strategy: the regular expression to match is

```
\A \d{4} \- \d{2} \- \d{2} \Z
```

that is, the input should consist of four digits, a hyphen, two digits, a hyphen, two digits. Any other input should result in the invalid ISO date message.

Here's my proposal that you can check with yours.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\validateISOdate}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_isodate_validate:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_isodate_validate:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4} \- \d{2} \- \d{2} \Z } { #1 }
   {
    \__projetmbc_isodate_validate:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    Invalid~date~'#1'~(format)
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_isodate_validate:n
 {
  \__projetmbc_isodate_process:w #1 \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_isodate_process:w #1 - #2 - #3 \q_stop
 {
  \__projetmbc_isodate_check:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_isodate_check:nnn
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF { \int_compare_p:nNn { #2 } < 1 } { \int_compare_p:nNn { #2 } > { 12 } }
   {
    Invalid~date~'#1-#2-#3'~(month)
   }
   {
    \__projetmbc_isodate_day:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_isodate_day:nnn
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } = { 0 }
   {
    Invalid~date~'#1-#2-#3'~(day)
   }
   {
    \__projetmbc_isodate_day_aux:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_isodate_day_aux:nnn
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } > { \__projetmbc_isodate_checkday:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   {
    Invalid~date~'#1-#2-#3'~(day)
   }
   {
    Valid~date~'#1-#2-#3'
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_isodate_checkday:nn
 {
  \int_case:nn { #2 }
   {
    {1}{31}
    {2}{\__projetmbc_isodate_february:n{#1}}
    {3}{31}
    {4}{30}
    {5}{31}
    {6}{30}
    {7}{31}
    {8}{31}
    {9}{30}
    {10}{31}
    {11}{30}
    {12}{31}
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_isodate_february:n
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
   {% year divisible by 4
    \int_compare_p:nNn { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } } = { 0 }
   } % AND
   {% year not divisible by 100 or divisible by 400
    \bool_lazy_or_p:nn
     {% not divisible by 100
      \int_compare_p:nNn { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } } > { 0 }
     }
     {% divisible by 400
      \int_compare_p:nNn { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 400 } } = { 0 }
     }
   }
   {29} % year is leap
   {28} % year is not leap
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \projetmbc_isodate_validate:n { ##1 } \par }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\test{
    2023-06-14,
    2023-09-24,
    2023-02-28,
    2024-02-29,
    400-02-29,
    300-02-29,
    2023-02-29,
    2024-02-30,
    2023-09-00,
    2023-09-32,
    2023-19-32,
    2023-00-29,
    2023-06-XX,
    2023-09-19,
    2023-09-20,
    -0001-12-24,
    2000-02-29,
    2100-02-29
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The missing tool for me was the `\bool_lazy_or_p` (@
Qrrbrbirlbel's user avatar
Qrrbrbirlbel has used it my previous post). I like the code, but I have question. Why don't you catch the value with the regex? Is it for performance reason you want to eat the hyphenated list of tokens. Can I steal your creation? :-)

Comment: @projetmbc When the input is in a very specific format (checked with the regex) capturing the items is easier and faster (and expandable, by the way) with delimited arguments.

Comment: I plan to write easy-to-understand tutorials about `LaTeX3` that I find very easy to use, but I still need to explore a lot more of the API...

Answer (score 5):

Let me summarize my findings and a few opinions:

1. Section 19.3 starts with “the actions at the left of the sequence are faster than those acting on the right“, so `\seq_pop_right:NN` seems to be a bad start. I'd swap that out for `\seq_pop_left:NN`.

   In my answer to your linked question, I've used the expandable `\seq_item:Nn` inside of an `int_compare` statement.
   Unfortunately, the manual does not mention the speed or efficiency of this seemingly direct access.

   At least then we don't have to use extra macros (“token lists”) for these things.

   If we allow delimited macros in a LaTeX3 approach I'd also revert back to my first version of [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/696444/1) and use those. For me, it is much more natural to use `#n` than deal with sequences.
2. That said, the manual also says that the second `N` from `\seq_pop_…:NN` is a token list but you're using a “string” variable (sure, both are just macros). The `n` of `\int_set:Nn` is an “int expr” with no further specifcation (but not a `N`).

   In the first solution (delimited macro) I don't need to access any sequence and in the second solution (heavy regex) I'm going to use `\seq_item:Nn` again. Unless you need to use those values again later I don't see the need to store them in some macro/token list/count.
3. The int variable is a real TeX count and `\int_set:Nn` basically does `#1=\numexpr#2\relax`.

   So the question becomes: is comparing numbers faster when one of them is a count and does it matter if you only use them once or twice per date? It already needs to be `\numexpr`ed once anyway to store the count in the first place.
4. I think more importantly is the efficiency note in section 20.5:   `\int_compare(_p):nNn(TF)` is five times faster than `\int_compare(_p):n(TF)` – I'm assuming because it only uses the TeX basics `=`, `<` and `>` and doesn't have to parse and convert `!=`, `>=` and `<=`.
5. Parsing of `&&`, `||` and `()` ought to be slower than directly accessing the functions And or Or. But that will be a compromise between speed, natural readability and logic.

   In my code I get away with simple binary Ors – lazy ones at that which `&&` and `||` are not (section 9.3).
6. If `\if_int_compare:w` is “allowed” in a *pure* LaTeX3 solution I would use `\if_case:w` for getting the last day of the month instead of a look-up in a sequence.

   Using `0` as the last day in cases of the month number being outside of the range 1–12 already can do our month check
7. You're mixing your `N`s and `n`s.

   `N` stands for a single token and `n` stands for a “set of token given in braces” (section 1.1) but the manual also states “if you use a single token for an `n` argument, all will be well”.

   However, I would do `\if_leap_year:n` and brace the `#1` after `\int_mod:nn` which would then not break `\if_leap_year_p:nTF { 2023 }`.

   The hard-coded `2` for the `\seq_set_item:Nnn` should be okay. (By the way, you set the second item of your 30/31 list with the first February and then it will always be that value and the special value will be gone forever.)
8. I've also incorporated some of the things @cfr mentioned in the comments, though whether a leap year tester must be an internal macro can be debated.

---

We can also create a regular expression that also catches illegal month and day numbers:

```
\regex_new:N \g__mbc_datex_format_rgx
\regex_set:Nn\g__mbc_datex_format_rgx { \A (\d+) \-
  (0* (?:[1-9]|1[012])) \- (0* (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])) \Z }
```

The only test to be done then is: last day of month in that year.
Again, in this example I'm using the whole l3regex system by extracting the values with it as well.

Testing with `l3benchmark` seems to reveal that this takes roughly double the time than the delimited macro approach with only the primitive `\if_case:w` check, unsuprisingly.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor, l3benchmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__mbc_lastday_of_month_in_year:nn {
  \if_case:w #1~
    0 \or: 31 \or: \__mbc_if_leap_year:nTF {#2}{29}{28} \or: 31
      \or: 30 \or: 31 \or: 30
      \or: 31 \or: 31 \or: 30
      \or: 31 \or: 30 \or: 31
      \else: 0 \fi:
}
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__mbc_if_leap_year:n #1 { TF } {
  \int_compare:nNnTF     {\int_mod:nn {#1} {   4 } } = { 0 } {
    \int_compare:nNnTF   {\int_mod:nn {#1} { 100 } } = { 0 } {
      \int_compare:nNnTF {\int_mod:nn {#1} { 400 } } = { 0 } {
        \prg_return_true:     % multiple of 400 →    leap year
      }{ \prg_return_false: } % multiple of 100 → no leap year
    }{ \prg_return_true: }    % multiple of   4 →    leap year
  }{ \prg_return_false: }  % no multiple of   4 → no leap year
}

\regex_new:N \g__mbc_date_format_rgx
\regex_set:Nn\g__mbc_date_format_rgx { \A \d+ \- \d+ \- \d+ \Z }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__mbc_if_validate_date:n #1 { TF }{
  \regex_match:NnTF \g__mbc_date_format_rgx { #1 } {
    \__mbc_datetest_parse:w #1 \q_stop
  }{ \prg_return_false: }
}
\cs_new:Npn \__mbc_datetest_parse:w #1 - #2 - #3 \q_stop {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF % case 0 and case else fail this for invalid months
    { \int_compare_p:nNn { #3 } < { 1 } }
    { \int_compare_p:nNn { #3 } >
      { \__mbc_lastday_of_month_in_year:nn { #2 } { #1 } } }
  { \prg_return_false: }
  { \prg_return_true:  }
}

%%% heavy regex solution
\regex_new:N \g__mbc_datex_format_rgx
\regex_set:Nn\g__mbc_datex_format_rgx { \A (\d+) \-
  (0* (?:[1-9]|1[012])) \- (0* (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])) \Z }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__mbc_if_validate_datex:n #1 { TF }{
  \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \g__mbc_datex_format_rgx { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {4} }
                       >
                       { \__mbc_lastday_of_month_in_year:nn
                         { \seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq {3} }
                         { \seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq {2} } }
    { \prg_return_false: }
    { \prg_return_true:  }
  }{ \prg_return_false: }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \ValidateJulianDate }{ m m m }{
  \__mbc_if_validate_date:nTF { #1 }{ #2 }{ #3 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \ValidateJulianDateX }{ m m m }{
  \__mbc_if_validate_datex:nTF { #1 }{ #2 }{ #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pgfkeys{
  tester/.code = \ValidateJulianDate {#1}{OK}{Not OK} and
                 \ValidateJulianDateX{#1}{OK}{Not OK}: #1\par\medskip}
\newcommand*\test[1]{\pgfkeys{tester/.list={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\section{OK}
\test{2023-06-14, 2023-09-24, 2023-02-28, 2024-02-29, 400-02-29}

\section{KO -- Invalid day}
\test{300-02-29, 2023-02-29, 2024-02-30, 2023-09-00, 2023-09-32}

\section{KO -- Invalid month}
\test{2023-19-32, 2023-00-29}

\section{KO -- Syntax error}
\test{2023-06-XX, 2023-09-19 2023-09-20, -0001-12-24}

\clearpage
\section{Table}
\ExplSyntaxOn\ttfamily
\foreach \v in {\ValidateJulianDate, \ValidateJulianDateX}{
  \expandafter \string \v : \par
  \benchmark_once:n {
    \foreach \m in {0, ..., 13}{
      \ifnum\int_mod:nn{\m-1}{3}=0\medskip\fi
      \foreach \d in {0, ..., 32}{
        \ifnum\int_mod:nn{\d+1}{10}=0\relax\space\fi
        \exp_args:Nx\v{2023-0\m-0\d}{1}{0}
      }
      \par
    }
  }
  \bigskip
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: About the internal bit: I only meant *if* something is meant to be internal .... There is a rather substantive explanation of 'integer expression' at the start of the documentation of that module. In the version I have it's section 20.1 pp.161-162, but the documentation of `\int_eval:n` etc. might help, too. It specifies what counts as `n` type here, which is slightly non-standard.

Comment: Good point for the catching regex but I will investigate if it is slower than using a basic one. For the leap year, I think useful to have a dedicated predicate. I will in

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. I will do a mix of your design choice and some of mine.

Comment: One question: I have binary outputs for the benchmarks. Why?

Comment: I keep your code in my folders. I plan to write easy-to-understand tutorials about `LaTeX3` that I find very easy to use, but I still need to explore a lot more of the API...

Comment: @projetmbc Well, if using a delimited macro is still allowed under LaTeX3 I'd prefer that too. Then we don't even have to deal with accessing the items in the sequence. It's just annoying we can't do this inline and need to define yet another macro. Please do write an easy-to-understand tutorial. Understanding the manual without examples isn't easy without sitting down and reading it from front to back. I rarely delve into L3 because the start of the learning curve is so steep.

Comment: By the way, my first version of [the previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/696444/1) uses a delimited macro to split the values. I thought using `l3regex` to catch these elements would be “neater”. There's also `xparse` with which we can preprocess arguments and split them at the `-` …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `xparse` is deprecated. For recent kernels, you no longer need it.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I meant the functionalities that were previously available by the `xparse` package. There should still be `> \SplitArgument { 2 } { - } m` which already gives us the values splitted at `-` and `-NoValue-` markers if the argument doesn't have enough hyphens. But checking for numbers is still needed then.

Comment: @projetmbc I've updated my answer. I've reverted back to my previous answer using delimited macros, I like them much more but I will leave my statements about the datatypes and the `N`/`n` discussion since the other answer doesn't go into this at all. The binary output is on purpose to make it easier to notice difference on a glance (and obvious mistakes).