# Handling \ifnum's "! Missing number, treated as zero."

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, comparison

Let's say I have a variable, which may - or may NOT - be a number; how can I handle the cases when it isn't a number, without crashing with "! Missing number, treated as zero." ?

In practical terms, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\def\mytestvar{4}

\ifnum\mytestvar=2 %
  \typeout{Test 1 true} %
\else %
  \typeout{Test 1 false (as expected)} %
\fi

\def\mytestvar{2}

\ifnum\mytestvar=2 %
  \typeout{Test 2 true (as expected)} %
\else %
  \typeout{Test 2 false} %
\fi

\def\mytestvar{ mistake}

\ifnum\mytestvar=2 %
  \typeout{Test 3 true} %
\else %
  \typeout{Test 3 false (as expected)} %
\fi

\def\mytestvar{2}

\ifnum\mytestvar=2 %
  \typeout{Test 4 true (as expected)} %
\else %
  \typeout{Test 4 false} %
\fi


\end{document}
```

This results with the output:

```
Test 1 false (as expected)
Test 2 true (as expected)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   m
l.23 \ifnum\mytestvar
                     =2 %
?
```

How can I make Test 3 pass as false (instead of crash), so that Test 4 can perform as well in the same run? Hopefully, by not including any additional packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\ifnum2=0\mytestvar`. If `\mytestvar` expands to a number the leading 0 doesn't matter, but if it isn't a number there is at least some number there, which also triggers the *false* branch.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the great tip, @MartinScharrer - wish I didn't have to wait 8 more minutes to accept `:)` Cheers!

Comment: In case `\mytestvar` is empty I'd add `\ifnum2=0\mytestvar\relax` or something to avoid unexpected consequences. Furthermore, bad things happen if `\mytestvar` starts with `2` followed by text. Maybe it would be better to first test whether `\mytestvar` is numeric at all, compare [Testing for number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7180/12850).

Comment: Thanks for the great link, @StephanLehmke - quite a nice collection of "isNum" type functions there; cheers!