# Adding up numbers

Tags: macros, conditionals

In a local class file I maintain, we have a system that can automatically add up numbers (in our case, marks for an assignment) and then output the sum.

I would like to develop it to add up *limited* non-integer input (and gracefully handle non-numeric input, i.e. simply output the parameter it is given, or otherwise catch this case). Specifically, I want it to handle half marks.

The interface I anticipate for users is a command, say `\half`, that can be applied to `add' half a mark to the running total, and render the half mark as a fraction.

Here is an outline document based on [egreg's answer to a similar-ish question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50131/96966).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{sum}

\makeatletter
\def\mycommand#1{%
  \afterassignment\get@args\count@=0#1\hfuzz#1\hfuzz}
\def\get@args#1\hfuzz#2\hfuzz{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    #2 is a number%
    \addtocounter{sum}{#2}
  \else
    #2 is not a number%
  \fi
}
\def\@dhalf{\(\frac12\)}
\gdef\@half{\@dhalf\gdef\half{\@@half}}
\gdef\@@half{\@dhalf\addtocounter{sum}{1}\gdef\half{\@half}}
\let\half\@half
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mycommand{\half}\par
\mycommand{1}\par
\mycommand{1\half}\par
\mycommand{2}\par
\mycommand{text}\par
Total is: \thesum

\end{document}
```

As you can see, adding up the half marks two-at-a-time to the `sum` counter is no problem. (I can also render a leftover half mark if one exists, although I haven't done that in the MWE.)  However, when you have, say, something like `1\half`, then this is "not a number" and thus the 1 is not added to the total.

I freely admit that part of my trouble is that I have only a superficial understanding of what's going on in the definition of `\mycommand` and `\get@args` to capture numbers, but in any case perhaps someone can suggest a way to get this to behave in the expected way?

Comment: "gracefully handle non-numeric input" - please refine/specify/clarify. ;-)

Comment: I've added a little. Basically I don't want it to throw an error. I suspect most solutions would then essentially give us a space where we could do anything we wanted with the non-numeric input. For example, the accepted answer outputs `FIX MARKS`, but this could easily be changed to whatever we wanted (including `#1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this implementation only one trailing `\half` is allowed, preceded or not by an integer. Spaces between the integer and `\half` are allowed.

The marks are stored locally, so you can use environments if you have multiple parts to be assessed different marks.

I used `\Marks` because `\marks` is already taken (an e-TeX primitive).

The idea is to first check for legal input and then to distinguish whether `\half` is present. In this case the “half” counter is incremented. At printing time, its value is divided by 2 and if the number of “half-marks” is odd, the fraction is appended.

The control sequence `\half` is actually a dummy, so for printing we must set it to `\frac{1}{2}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_rbrignall_mark_integer_int
\int_new:N \l_rbrignall_mark_half_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\Marks}{m}
 {% print and store
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A [[:digit:]]* \s* \c{half}? \Z } { #1 }
   {% good input
    $\cs_set:Npn \half {\frac{1}{2}} #1$ % print
    \rbrignall_store:n { #1 }            % store
   }
   { \mbox{FIX~MARKS!!!} }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\half}{}{}% dummy

\NewDocumentCommand{\TotalMarks}{}
 {
  $
  \int_eval:n
   {
    \l_rbrignall_mark_integer_int + \int_div_truncate:nn {\l_rbrignall_mark_half_int}{2}
   }
  \int_if_odd:nT { \l_rbrignall_mark_half_int } { \frac{1}{2} }
  $
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rbrignall_store:n
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnT { #1 } { \half } { \int_incr:N \l_rbrignall_mark_half_int }
  \int_add:Nn \l_rbrignall_mark_integer_int { 0#1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textbf{Test 1}

\begingroup % for testing more examples
\Marks{\half}\par
\Marks{1}\par
\Marks{1 \half}\par
\Marks{2}\par
\Marks{text}\par
Total is: \TotalMarks\par
\endgroup

\bigskip

\textbf{Test 2}

\begingroup % for testing more examples
\Marks{\half}\par
\Marks{1\half}\par
\Marks{1 \half}\par
\Marks{2}\par
Total is: \TotalMarks\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting this excellent answer as it most faithfully answers the question. But I also encourage visitors to this page to look at matexmatics answer too (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713094/96966).

Comment: In case of 1/2 `\TotalMarks` yields`0\frac{1}{2}` instead of just `\frac{1}{2}`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Corner case, but I'd say it's quite unlikely to happen…

Comment: In my use case, totals should generally be integers if everything adds up correctly. One could presumably suppress the 0 in such cases (as I do in my solution).

Answer (score 2):

The code below defines a command `\addmark` and a command `\totalmarks`. Inside `\addmark`, `\half` can be used to add 0.5 points. This command can be used multiple times. For example, `\half\half` adds 1 and `2\half 3` adds 5.5.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l__rbrignall_total_fp
\tl_new:N \l__rbrignall_mark_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \addmark { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__rbrignall_mark_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__rbrignall_mark_tl { \half } { + 0.5 + }
    \fp_add:Nn \l__rbrignall_total_fp { \l__rbrignall_mark_tl + 0 }%note the + 0 for the case that #1 ends with \half
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \totalmarks { }
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { \l__rbrignall_total_fp } = { 0.5 }
      { $ \frac { 1 } { 2 } $ }
      {
        \fp_compare:nNnTF { \l__rbrignall_total_fp - trunc ( \l__rbrignall_total_fp , 0 ) } = { 0 }
          { \fp_use:N \l__rbrignall_total_fp }
          { \fp_eval:n { \l__rbrignall_total_fp - 0.5 } $ \frac { 1 } { 2 } $ }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\addmark{\half}\totalmarks

\addmark{\half\half}\totalmarks

\addmark{1\half}\totalmarks

\addmark{2\half 3}\totalmarks

\addmark{4\half 5\half}\totalmarks
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh this is clever, very clever. Bonus points for being able to add up multiple different numbers (and halves) inside a single `\addmark` (as this is a very real use case which I'd assumed would be a Step Too Far).

Answer (score 2):

There are some great other answers using Latex3, but while I was offline I managed to combine an approach given in a (now deleted) partial answer which uses lengths instead of a counter (thanks to the poster for the idea!), with [the approach in this answer about checking for floating points numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167941/96966).

For completeness, I'll share the result here. Note, the `\half` command is actually now a bit defunct (just enter floating point decimals) so arguably this answers a slightly different question to the one I asked, but here it is anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`P=12
\catcode`T=12
\lowercase{%
   \def\x{%
      \def\my@rem@pt##1.##2PT{%
        \ifnum##2=5
          \ifnum##1=0\else##1\fi% integer part
          \(\frac12\)% if 0.5, print 1/2
        \else % Could capture more fractions here
           ##1%
           \ifnum##2=0% if no decimal part do nothing more
           \else.##2% otherwise print the decimal
           \fi
         \fi
      }%
   }%
}\expandafter\endgroup\x

\newlength{\mysum}
\newlength{\mkval}
\newcommand{\thesum}{\expandafter\my@rem@pt\the\mysum}

\newcommand*{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\half{.5}%
  \newif\if@nan\@nanfalse%
  \newif\if@fndpt\@fndptfalse%
  \edef\tmp{\testleadneg#1\relax}%
  \expandafter\testreal\tmp\relax%
  \if@nan%
    \def\half{\(\frac12\)}%
    #1%
  \else\global\advance\mysum#1\p@%
  \setlength{\mkval}{#1pt}%
  \expandafter\my@rem@pt\the\mkval
\fi
   \endgroup%
}

\def\testreal#1#2\relax{%
\if.#1\if@fndpt\@nantrue\else\@fndpttrue\fi\else
\if1#1\else\if2#1\else\if3#1\else\if4#1\else
\if5#1\else\if6#1\else\if7#1\else\if8#1\else
\if9#1\else\if0#1\else\@nantrue%
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
\if@nan\else\if\relax#2\else\testreal#2\relax\fi\fi}
%
\def\testleadneg#1#2\relax{\if-#1#2\else#1#2\fi}
%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
Mark&Total\\\hline
\mycommand{0}&\thesum\\
\mycommand{\half}&\thesum\\
\mycommand{1}&\thesum\\
\mycommand{1.5}&\thesum\\
\mycommand{2\half}&\thesum\\
\mycommand{.2}&\thesum\\
\mycommand{text 2}&\thesum\\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image: Table output of latex file]

Answer (score 1):

As far as the author of the initial release of this answer knows, TeX by means of registers and primitives can do arithmetic in the range -2<sup>31</sup>+1  to +2<sup>31</sup>-1.

If

- you need this only for integers and fractions ½ and
- you don't mind reducing to a range of -2<sup>30</sup>+1  to +2<sup>30</sup>-1,

then you can have TeX maintain

- a macro `\doublesum`, which, instead of wasting a `\count`-register,  is to hold the double of the sum to calculate,
- a macro `\thesum`, which delivers the result of halving `\doublesum` as a sequence of digits and probably one instance of `\frac{1}{2}`,
- a macro `\addtosum`, which is used for adding the double of its argument to `\doublesum`,
- a macro `\clearsum`, which defines `\doublesum` empty.

(By the way, `\sum` is already defined in TeX/LaTeX and is used for obtaining in mathematical typesetting the uppercase sigma with subscript/superscript limits for indices that is often used with sums of elements that are indexed. So don't be tempted to accidentally override `\sum` in the course of implementing your own "infrastructure" of macros that have the phrase "sum" in their name.)

The author of the initial release of this answer didn't bother implementing checking whether the argument of `\addtosum` is of correct form.

On the one hand implementing some sort of checking for restricting input to specific constellations of explicit character tokens out of specific classes of character tokens (signs, digits, spaces) trailed by at most one control word token `\half` is already shown in other answers.

On the other hand the question does not precisely specify what to consider "correct form".
E.g., if any TeX ⟨number⟩ quantity—⟨number⟩ is explained in Backus-Naur-notation in "Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode" of the TeXbook; ε-TeX and pdfTeX and LuaTeX and XeTeX and other TeX engines extend the concept of TeX's ⟨number⟩—plus probably a single instance of the control word token `\half` surrounded by optional spaces is to be accepted, the question arises of how to interpret things like `\numexpr\mycounter\relax\half` while the current value of `\mycounter` is 0. Is that 0½? If so: As 0=-0, is 0½=-0½? Is that ½ or is that -½?
Besides this, expansion usually is not suppressed when TeX gathers tokens of a ⟨number⟩. Therefore proper checking would probably require implementing an algorithm in TeX for checking whether the tokens forming the argument expand to a set of tokens that forms valid ⟨optional signs⟩ or a complete valid ⟨number⟩ probably trailed by an optional control word token `\half` that might be surrounded by  ⟨optional spaces⟩/⟨one optional space⟩ in case you manage to get that behind a control word token. So one would face the task of implementing an algorithm in TeX for checking the result of expansion. When it is about expansion of the tokens of an argument of a macro, these tokens themselves can be considered aspects of implementations of expansion-driven algorithms. So the task of implementing an algorithm for checking the result of expansion beneath other things would require checking whether the algorithm made up by the tokens that form the argument

- terminates without errors.
- terminates without unwanted side-effects that probably won't yield error messages (as in edge cases can happen, e.g., when arranging tokens of a macro argument so that expanding them leads to gobbling/re-arranging subsequent tokens that do not belong to the argument but are components of the ⟨replacement text⟩ of some macro's ⟨definition⟩—that macro in turn might belong to the macro-mechanism that forms the checking-routine…— and thus by the implementer of the macro-mechanism are intended as means for keeping the expansion-chain going properly).
- terminates at all.

This is not trivial in TeX and the author of the initial release of this answer is reminded of the halting problem.

```latex
\makeatletter
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00 }%
\newcommand\@twooftwo[2]{#1#2}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\doublesum{}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*\addtosum[1]{%
  \edef\doublesum{%
    \the\numexpr(0\doublesum)+(\addtosumSplitAtHalf#1\half Z\relax)%
        \relax
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\addtosumSplitAtHalf{%
  \def\addtosumSplitAtHalf#1\half#2\relax{%
    (#1+0)*2
    \ifx#2Z\else
    % The token \half is there, thus
    % - in case the number is negative or 0 is prefixed by a
    %   minus sign subtract 1,
    % - in case the number is positive or 0 is not prefixed by a
    %   minus sign add 1.
      \ifnum\numexpr(#1+0)\relax=0 %
        \ifnum\numexpr(#11)\relax<0 -\else+\fi 
      \else
        \ifnum\numexpr(#1+0)\relax<0 -\else+\fi 
      \fi
    1\fi
  }%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\clearsum{\def\doublesum{}}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\thesum{%
  \romannumeral
  % Check if the integer-part of the sum is 0.
  \ifnum
    \numexpr
      (0\doublesum)/2%
      \ifodd\numexpr(0\doublesum)\relax
        \ifnum\numexpr(0\doublesum)\relax>0 -\else+\fi1%
      \fi
    \relax=0 %
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    % In case the integer-part of the sum is 0 and the doubled sum is
    % even, no rounding occured, thus just print 0. In case of the
    % doubled sum being odd, rounding occurred, so 1/2 or -1/2 needs
    % to be delivered depending on whether the doubled sum is positive
    % or negative.
    \ifodd\numexpr(0\doublesum)\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \ifnum\numexpr(0\doublesum)\relax<0 %
        \expandafter\stopromannumeral\expandafter-%
      \else
        \expandafter\stopromannumeral
      \fi
      \frac{1}{2}%
    }%
    {\stopromannumeral0}%
  }{%
    % In case the integer-part of the sum is not 0, calculate it
    % by halving the doubled via \numexpr's division where rounding
    % occurs in case the doubled sum is odd. In case of roundig 
    % and the number being positive subtract 1 otherwise add 1.
    % In case of rounding also deliver 1/2.
    \expandafter\stopromannumeral
    \the\numexpr
    (0\doublesum)/2%
    \ifodd\numexpr(0\doublesum)\relax\ifnum\numexpr(0\doublesum)\relax
    >0 -\else+\fi1\expandafter\@twooftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
    \relax{\frac{1}{2}}%
  }%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% \addtosum and \clearsum can be prefixed by \global.
% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result of \thesum is generated
% within two expansion steps.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\global\clearsum \(\thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 7 = \global\addtosum{-7} \thesum\) 
\par\(\thesum + 3 = \global\addtosum{3} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 1\frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{1\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 2\frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{-2\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 5 = \global\addtosum{5} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 7 = \global\addtosum{7} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 3 = \global\addtosum{-3} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 1\frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{-1\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 2\frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{+2\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 5 = \global\addtosum{-5} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 1 = \global\addtosum{-1} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + \frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{0\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + \frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + \frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{+\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + \frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{+0\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - \frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{-0\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - \frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{-\half} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum - 0 = \global\addtosum{-0} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 0 = \global\addtosum{+0} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 0 = \global\addtosum{0} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 0 = \global\addtosum{} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 0 = \global\addtosum{+} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 0 = \global\addtosum{-} \thesum\)
\par\(\thesum + 15\frac{1}{2} = \global\addtosum{15\half} \thesum\)

\edef\SomeSumMacro{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\thesum}%
}

\par The sum calculated so far is stored in the macro
\verb|\SomeSumMacro| whose meaning is:\\
\texttt{\meaning\SomeSumMacro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

> ```latex
> \documentclass{article}
> \newcounter{sum}
>
> \makeatletter
> \def\mycommand#1{%
>   \afterassignment\get@args\count@=0#1\hfuzz#1\hfuzz}
> \def\get@args#1\hfuzz#2\hfuzz{%
>   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
>     #2 is a number%
>     \addtocounter{sum}{#2}
>   \else
>     #2 is not a number%
>   \fi
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```latex
> \makeatother
> ```
>
> [...]
> I freely admit that part of my trouble is that I have only a superficial understanding of what's going on in the definition of `\mycommand` and `\get@args` to capture numbers,
> [...]

`\mycommand` is a macro. When expanding it, TeX grabs an undelimited argument and delivers `\mycommand`'s ⟨replacement text⟩ with the parameter `#1` replaced by the tokens that form the argument. Expanding `\mycommand` yields the following:

```
\afterassignment\get@args
\count@=0⟨\mycommand's argument⟩\hfuzz⟨\mycommand's argument⟩\hfuzz
```

The `\afterassignment`-directive causes TeX to insert the token `\get@args` as soon as all tokens needed for doing the assignment to the `\count`-register denoted by the ⟨countdef token⟩ `\count@` are gathered from the token-stream and processed:
As there is a leading `0`, the process of gathering tokens belonging to the ⟨number⟩ of the assignment and hereby expanding things stops as soon as a non-digit is encountered. (Or as soon as it is clear that the number denoted by ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ is too big. In this case you are informed via a low-level TeX error message.) After the assignment is performed, TeX is after the assignment and therefore the token `\get@args` is inserted right before the first token which in the course of gathering the ⟨number⟩ of the assignment is considered to not be a component of that  ⟨number⟩.

In case  ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ (after expansion) either yields emptiness or consists only of digits that don't form a number that is too big, this is the first token `\hfuzz` coming from the ⟨replacement text⟩ of `\mycommand`.

Then `\get@args` grabs everything up to the first token `\hfuzz` as its first `\hfuzz`-delimited argument and ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ as its second argument delimited by the second token `\hfuzz`. Therefore, in case ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ in the course of gathering the tokens of the ⟨number⟩ for the `\count@`-assignment did not yield emptiness or only digits, `\get@args`'s first argument is not empty. (Emptiness is tested via `\if\relax\detokenize{\get@args's 1st argument⟩}\relax⟨empty⟩else⟨not empty⟩\fi`.)
In this case `\get@args`'s second argument, which holds ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ is used for delivering `⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ is not a number`.  In case `\get@args`'s first argument is empty, gathering tokens for the ⟨number⟩ of the assignment did not lead to leaving things that are not a component of a ⟨number⟩ and you get `⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ is a number\addtocounter{sum}{⟨\mycommand's argument⟩}`.

The test is not totally safe.
E.g., the test assumes 0 in case ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ is blank, which, however, is not necessarily to be considered undesired/erroneous behavior.
E.g., the test fails in case ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ expands to digits trailed by the token `\hfuzz`.
E.g., the test fails in case expanding ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ in the course of gathering tokens belonging to the ⟨number⟩ leads to attempting to expand things where attempting expansion yields error messages (e.g. undefined tokens, unbalanced `\if..`/`\else`/`\fi`, unbalanced `\csname`/`\endcsname`, `\the` trailed by s.th. that is not an ⟨internal quantity⟩,…).
E.g., the test fails in case expanding ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ in the course of gathering tokens belonging to the ⟨number⟩ leads to triggering  expansion-cascades by things like `\expanded`/`\romannumeral`/`\the`/`\if`/`\number` etc which remove/rearrange some of the subsequent tokens `\hfuzz⟨\mycommand's argument⟩\hfuzz`, so that usage of `\get@args` does not match its definition…).
E.g., the test fails in case expanding ⟨\mycommand's argument⟩ tricks TeX into some sort of tail-recursive loop which either never ends or at some stage ends with a low level error message about TeX's memory capacity being exceeded or the number being too big or the like as would be the case, e.g., with things like `\mycommand{3\NastyMacro}` when `\NastyMacro` is defined as `\def\NastyMacro{0\NastyMacro}` or `\def\NastyMacro{\NastyMacro0}` or `\def\NastyMacro{\NastyMacro 1}` or `\def\NastyMacro{1\NastyMacro}`.