# Classicthesis chapter title formatting

Tags: spacing, formatting, classicthesis

How can I modify ClassicThesis to format chapter headings with the word "Chapter" followed by the roman numeral chapter number, a verticle space, and the chapter title? As many know, the default looks like:

[image: Default beginning of a chapter]

While the desired (nay, required) would look like:

[image: Desired beginning of a chapter]

I have written the whole thing using lyx, and have been able to change many things to match required formatting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Christian, Is there a proper way to post a MWE when using LyX instead of LaTeX proper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following code to your preamble, just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
\def\ifNumPutRoman#1{%
  \if!\ifnum9<1#1!\else_\fi
    \RNum{#1}\else#1\fi}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]%             
        {\relax}
        {\centering{CHAPTER \ifNumPutRoman{\thechapter}} \\ }%
        {10pt}%
        {\centering\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{2\baselineskip}]%
```

Which gives you this:
[image]

`\RNum` converts `thechapter` to roman numerics, however, it first needs to be checked if it is a number or not. This could happen when `\chapter{}` is called in appendix part. The next command, `\ifNumPutRoman` takes care of this. Credit for this check goes to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7183/22492) answer.

Comment: Pouya, thanks for your answer. This code works as advertised when added to the preamble in a LyX classicthesis document.