# Problems with acro package and greek babel?

Tags: koma-script, babel, acronyms, greek, acro

Well, I need to create an acronym list in my thesis, I was using the `acronym`package before for that. Since I updated several package and my old preamble had too much error, I decided to create another `main.tex` file and build there again the preamble. Has been hard to do and order the packages for avoid errors. All was fine until yesterday when I added greek polytonic  for few notes that I compose like sidenotes with the `snotez` package, and then started the problems.

At first the errors were related to babel and greek, bunt now that works fine. My problem now are the acronyms that yesterday were fine.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,fontsize=10pt,draft=false}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,spanish.mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{snotez}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Acronyms
\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{lbd}{
 short = LBD , 
 long = Lipoproteinas de baja densidad ,
 foreign = Low-Density Lipoprotein
}
\DeclareAcronym{vop}{
 short = VOP , 
 long = Velocidad de onda de pulso ,
 foreign = Pulse Wave Velocity
}
\DeclareAcronym{ifs}{
 short = IFS , 
 long = Interacción fluido-sólido ,
 foreign = Fluid-Solid/Structure Interaction
}

\DeclareAcronym{hgo}{
 short = HGO , 
 long = modelo de Holzapfel-Gasser-Ogden
}

\DeclareAcronym{aha}{
 short = AHA , 
 long = Asociación Americana del Corazón ,
 foreign = American Heart Asociation
}
\DeclareAcronym{wss}{
 short = WSS , 
 long = Esfuerzo cortante de pared ,
 foreign = Wall Shear Stress
}    

\DeclareAcronym{adina}{
 short = ADINA ,
 long  =  Automatic Dynamic Incremental Nonlinear Analysis ,
 class = software
}    

\begin{document}

\minisec{Arteriosclerosis}

Es un término genérico\sidenote{Del griego {\selectlanguage{greek} \textgreek{'arthr'ia}} \emph{arteria} y {\selectlanguage{greek} \textgreek{skl'hrwsic}} \emph{cicatriz, rigidez}.} que fue creado por Jean Georges Chrétien Frédéric Martin Lobstein.

Este capítulo tiene como objetivo proporcionar una descripción de las ecuaciones matemáticas que rigen y el algoritmo desarrollado para la modelación computacional \ac{ifs} del flujo sanguíneo y las geometrías del modelo utilizadas en el estudio.

La \ac{dfc} descompone la geometría en pequeñas celdas y por tanto tiene como objetivo resolver las ecuaciones que rigen para cada celda.

En la actualidad, varios paquetes de software como \ac{adina} proporcionan esta capacidad. Todos estos programas emplean el método de elementos finitos para resolver las ecuaciones de flujo. Este es el método preferido para resolver simulaciones \ac{ifs} de problemas estructurales, ya que es uno de los mejores métodos disponibles. 

\printacronyms[exclude-classes=software]
\printacronyms[include-classes=software, name={Software}]    
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile I get few errors, one of them says:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
\global
l.186 \cnltx@tmpa
A one-character control sequence belongs after a ` mark.
So I'm essentially inserting \0 here.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

another:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> 2\0
9/\9/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
l.6 Trim spaces around a token list]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

In the first case I understand that the error is because the `cnltx` package wasn't load before or something else. I don't use it, and I want to believe that one of the several packages I've got should load it.

If you want to see the original log file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qm3a5w2j50l2r83/Perestroila.log?dl=0), and the real preamble is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7rv7x22wyo7802/Full%20Preamble.tex?dl=0).

Comment: Unrelated: `\textgreek{...}` is sufficient and `\selectlanguage{greek}` is to be removed as it just adds noise (and possible errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be unrelated, but I had problems with `babel` when I initially loaded the `acro` package. I solved them (perhaps fortuitously) by loading `acro` before `babel`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}  % KOMA report class

\usepackage{acro}  % Define and list acronyms (load before {babel})
\usepackage[greek, UKenglish]{babel}  % Provides language support (load after {acro})
```

Not a very technical answer, but it might be worth a shot!

Comment: This surely works provided also `LGR` is not loaded with `fontenc` prior to `acro`. Actually loading `fontenc` with the `LGR` option is not required any more for Greek. Very good as a temporary workaround.

Comment: So should I load `acro` before `babel` and remove `LGR` from the options of `fontenc`?

Comment: It's worth a try – you can always reverse the change if it doesn't work!

Comment: O.O it works!!! I moved the line where I load `acro` before `babel` and `xcolor` clashed >_< Later I moved `xcolor` up `babel` and it works!!! \m/ I loaded almost everything (but `csquotes` and `biblatex` yet) and runs well. Thanks for the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in `cnltx-base.sty`. The problem is on line 179 of `cnltx-base.sty`

```
179 \edef\cnltx@tmpa{\catcode`\%=\the\catcode`\% \catcode`\&=\the\catcode`\&}
```

where the code is not sufficiently defensive; it should be

```
179 \edef\cnltx@tmpa{\catcode`\noexpand\%=\the\catcode`\% \catcode`\noexpand\&=\the\catcode`\& }
```

so a possible change of meaning of `\%` and `\&` will not give problems.

What happens is that `\&` becomes

```
> \&=macro:
->\LGR-cmd \&\LGR\& .
```

when Greek is loaded, and the expansion of this macro triggered by `\edef` is completely useless for the purpose of the definition. There is no problem with the second `\&` because this is examined as part of the expansion of `\the`, so TeX doesn't expand it.

The first `\%` wouldn't need `\noexpand` in front of it, but better safe than sorry.

---

A possibly better fix that doesn't require category code restoration. The code in `cnltx-base.sty` (line numbers added for clarity)

```
175 % an idea by Herbert Voß (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7183/5049):
176 %   make the test character an (hopefully extremely) unlikely % with
177 %   catcode!=14;  let's make & a temporary comment char
178 %   save both catcodes just in case someone changed the defaults:
179 \edef\cnltx@tmpa{\catcode`\%=\the\catcode`\% \catcode`\&=\the\catcode`\&}
180 \catcode`\%=3
181 \catcode`\&=14
182 & the test:
183 \newcommand*\cnltx@ifisnum[1]{&
184   \iftest{\if%\ifnum9<1#1%\else_\fi}&
185 }
186 \cnltx@tmpa
```

can become

```
% an idea by Herbert Voß (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7183/5049):
%   make the test character an (hopefully extremely) unlikely % with
%   catcode!=14 
% the test:
\begingroup
  \catcode`\$=\thr@@ % ensure it's what we want
  \lccode`\$=`\%
  \lccode`\1=\z@ % just to be really sure
  \lccode`\9=\z@ % just to be really sure
  \lccode`\_=\z@ % just to be really sure
  \lccode`\#=\z@ % just to be really sure
  \lccode`\<=\z@ % just to be really sure
  \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newcommand*\cnltx@ifisnum[1]{%
    \iftest{\if$\ifnum9<1#1$\else_\fi}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: In a nutshell I have to edit the `cnltx-base.sty` file for fix that bug... I'll try to do it, thanks.

Comment: @Aradnix I'd wait for Clemens to fix it. In the meantime you can use Mark Birtwistle's workaround.

Comment: I did it and it works fine!!! Thanks to you both.