# More problems with acro package and MikTeX 2.9: l3sort and l3kernel packages

Tags: miktex, acro

Well, yesterday I posted here [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208768/problems-with-acro-package-and-greek-babel/208786#208786). I could solve that problem on my WS with Windows 7 and MikTeX 2.9 (64 bits) with the trick suggested by Mark Birtwistle. Nevertheless, today, working on my PC at the Institute (where I use MikTeX 2.9 on Windows XP) I have another unexpected and strange error.

First, from my previous question, the MWE where I corrected the previous errors is:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,fontsize=10pt,draft=false}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,spanish.mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{snotez}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Acronyms    

\DeclareAcronym{ifs}{
 short = IFS , 
 long = Interacción fluido-sólido ,
 foreign = Fluid-Solid/Structure Interaction
}    
\DeclareAcronym{dfc}{
 short = DFC , 
 long = Dinámica de fluidos computacional ,
 foreign = Computational Fluid Dynamics
}
\DeclareAcronym{adina}{
 short = ADINA ,
 long  =  Automatic Dynamic Incremental Nonlinear Analysis ,
 class = software
}    

\begin{document}

\minisec{Arteriosclerosis}

Es un término genérico\sidenote{Del griego {\selectlanguage{greek} \textgreek{'arthr'ia}} \emph{arteria} y {\selectlanguage{greek} \textgreek{skl'hrwsic}} \emph{cicatriz, rigidez}.} que fue creado por Jean Georges Chrétien Frédéric Martin Lobstein.

Este capítulo tiene como objetivo proporcionar una descripción de las ecuaciones matemáticas que rigen y el algoritmo desarrollado para la modelación computacional \ac{ifs} del flujo sanguíneo y las geometrías del modelo utilizadas en el estudio.

La \ac{dfc} descompone la geometría en pequeñas celdas y por tanto tiene como objetivo resolver las ecuaciones que rigen para cada celda.

En la actualidad, varios paquetes de software como \ac{adina} proporcionan esta capacidad. Todos estos programas emplean el método de elementos finitos para resolver las ecuaciones de flujo. Este es el método preferido para resolver simulaciones \ac{ifs} de problemas estructurales, ya que es uno de los mejores métodos disponibles. 

\printacronyms[exclude-classes=software]
\printacronyms[include-classes=software, name={Software}]    
\end{document}
```

I moved up the line where I load `acro` but as I had a clash with `xcolor` I moved it also. I put both before load `babel`. I know I can simplify `{\selectlanguage{greek} \textgreek{ }}` but I I haven't tried it yet.

Well, when I try to run the original file, the `main.tex` I have new errors:

```
! Package l3sort Error: Support package l3kernel too old.
See the l3sort package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.61 }
Please install an up to date version of l3kernel
using your TeX package manager or from CTAN.
Loading l3sort will abort!
```

and:

```
! Package acro Error: Support package expl3 too old.
See the acro package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.50 }
You need to update your installation of the bundles 'l3kernel' and 'l3packages'
.
Loading acro will abort!
```

It was strange for me. I try to keep updated both installations. The first I did when I saw that was update the packages, that packages were from February 2014, not too old for me. I updated and later I refreshed FNBD and updated formats. All as an admin user.

I try to run it again but the errors remain. I searched for updates but there are not new updates for me today. This is a little bit tragic for me, because I have to finish everything About my thesis) in less than a week and I haven't biber on my other installation (it is 64 bits and I have not a `cygwin.dll` file) and I have to add references, what I do on this machine, but I can't with these errors.

Meanwhile this weekend I'll try to install linux and TeXLive2014 this weekend. Again if you want to see the original log file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40178573/Tesis/iimas/Full%20Preamble.log), and the real preamble is [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40178573/Tesis/iimas/Full%20Preamble.tex). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think 'tragic' is a bit strong, even if it is your thesis. In any case, I don't recommend suing anybody ;).

Comment: I can't (try to) compile your code to reproduce the error because the acronym `dfc` is undefined. Please fix your code so that it is as close to compiling as you can manage. That way, just the real errors should be left when people try to run it.

Comment: Don't worry, I can't sue myself. ;)

Comment: It is a type: you say that you 'sue MiKTeX...' (though only, apparently, on XP so it is a quite specific lawsuit). It seems I can't reproduce the problem anyway. I guess it works with TeX Live.

Comment: You don't need to install GNU/Linux to install TL, do you? Why not just install TL? Or make one of those portable versions?

Comment: @cfr You're right, I corrected the lines of the MWE for you can compile it. And it was a type :P was _use_ not _sue_ as you said hahahaha. Finally why linux? Because I miss linux, I feel more comfortable there, and because the HDD of the WS has not space for TL. Maybe the portable version could works fine.The plan D is to finish it on the Mac.

Comment: Fair enough. It would certainly be more efficient for me to install GNU/Linux than mess around in Windows. But then, I'd delete Windows while I was at it, so I'm a bit weird.

Comment: @cfr I don't know where you get that I'll erase Windows, so I have to use it for various other things, I mean to install Linux on another machine that I have without use.

Comment: I didn't say ***you*** would erase Windows. I said that ***I*** would do so. That is not at all the same thing since you and I are not identical.

Comment: @cfr Hahahaha I see, I misunderstood your comment, sorry.

Comment: If you have a miktex multiuser installation: don't run  the update manager only in admin mode but also as user. And don't use the cygwin biber. Get the one in biberMSWIN.zip.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the update advice, and I don't use cygwin biber, I use normal biber here. But at home since I have installed MikTeX 2.9 (64 bits) without biber I tried to install there from biberMSWIN.zip but it doesn't works and always asks me for a cygwin dll file that I haven't installed. **In a nutshell**: here I have biber, but my `main.tex` file doesn't runs, and at home it runs but I haven't biber.

Comment: Well you mentioned a cygwin.dll, this indicates that a cygwin biber is around.

Comment: That's right but in the other machine, where I work fine but without biber yet.

Comment: @cfr I made a portable installation of MikTeX, but Biber there is the version 0.99d!!! instead of the 1.9 I had in Win XP or the version 1.8 in TeXLive2014, that's odd and useless for me.

Comment: I suggested a portable installation of TL. If the problem is that MiKTeX's version is too old, I wouldn't expect a portable edition to be any better.

Comment: Can 64 bit Windows not run 32 bit binaries? I would be quite stuck if the same were true of GNU/Linux. (Given the appropriate libraries, of course, but that is usually quite simple.)

Comment: @cfr pleaso don't chase aradnix in the next texsystem. The biber in miktex is naturally not to old - and even if it were it would be easy to replace biber executable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know anything about MiKTeX but I had gathered that the problem was that biber was not available from 64 bit MiKTeX but that it worked fine when it was available with 32 bit MiKTeX. Hence the question about binaries. But since this a solution is needed rather quickly, a portable installation of TL could potentially be one option. But actually I did not suggest TL in the first place: aradnix did. I only said that it worked for me with TL. (But some of the comments have been deleted, I think, so this is not obvious now.)

Comment: Is this resolved? Either way it now looks to me like a candidate for closing as off-topic…

Comment: I don't understand why this would be off-topic. And I don't know if the issue with the package is solved. What can I do?

Comment: @Aradnix Because the errors both vanish in an up to date TeX distribution. By convention we close questions which are resolved with an update as off-topic…

Comment: Well, the close it.

Comment: @Aradnix sorry – I would have reponded early but you didn't ping me (my name with an @ in front) so I didn't get notified of your answer. My initial question was: is this issue solved for you? I assume you did make an update with MiKTeX's package manager?

Comment: @clemens Sorry, I forgot to ping you in my earlier comments. Answering your last question: theoretically the problem should be solved with the last release of the `acro` package and a newr version of the l3kernel libray it uses. But nowadays MikTeX is a mess and is very hard to update it without break something else. So I don't know if it's solved in that distro. But in TeXlive it works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update