# Insert or apply a decision structure to sequence or list

Tags: conditionals, comma-separated-list

I would like to make the function calls `\findLargest` in the MWE below a little more dynamic and compact.

As demonstrated in the example below, I can store glossaries values and include them in the comparison.

I would like to change it however so that the call:  `\findLargest{0.001,value}` can test if the elements of the list are numeric or are gls labels.

To do this I think the code below would require a command or step implemented before the largest number search call that would apply an if statement that would carry out `if is numeric` type logic. (if such a thing is possible).  If false (not numeric) I would want the index element of the list to be replaced by the result of `\glsentryname{i}`

This is tough for me to visualize as I am used to programming in languages that have manually defined loops and thus it's easy for me to insert decision structures and new variables within the loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newglossaryentry{value}{name={0.022}, first={0.022}, description={0.022} }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\findLargest}{ om }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% separator is a comma, directly use \fp_eval:n { max ( #2 ) }
    \engbird_compute_max:n { #2 }
   }
   {% we need to pass the separator
    \engbird_find_largest:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_engbird_largest_seq
\tl_new:N \l_engbird_largest_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \engbird_find_largest:nn #1 #2
 {
  % split the input at the stated separator
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_engbird_largest_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % build a comma separated list
  \tl_set:Nx \l_engbird_largest_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_engbird_largest_seq {,} }
  % compute the max
  \engbird_compute_max:V \l_engbird_largest_tl
 }
% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Npn \engbird_compute_max:n #1
 {
  \fp_eval:n { max (#1) }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \engbird_compute_max:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent
\findLargest{1, 2 ,3, 6, 3,1} \\
\findLargest[;]{ 1.5 ; sqrt(2) ; pi/2 } \\
\findLargest{0.00001,\glsentryname{value}} \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do?  As it stands `\glsentryname{value}` is being expanded before the test is applied and it is correctly printing the largest value.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The expansion and logic in the function work perfectly.  I am just trying to automate the recognition of the gls label so that I don't have to include it in the function call itself.  My labels are extremely complicated strings and these functions are nested very deep, it would be helpful to move the `\glsentryname` addition to the function and dynamically apply it.

Comment: OK.  Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7180/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the link - I had allready bookmarked this one away because it was likely more appropriate to test for a number than a gls label.  It wasn't so much the test that is problematic, but how to apply it to a given element of a list.  For example unlike a C for loop, I don't believe I have access to the individual elements of the list as they are iterated through.  Maybe this is where I am wrong, but in the example above the iteration seems to be handled internally by max()