# How to define new command for \{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}?

Tags: macros, conditionals, math-operators

I want to make a new command that has three arguments:

1. symbol (`e, \omega,\cdots`)
2. superscript or subscript (`^` or `_`)
3. counter (`n`)

If n=3 then returns

```
\set{a}{^}{3}    ====> output: {a^1,a^2,a^3}
```

otherwise the output is as follow

```
\set{e}{_}{n}    ====> output: {e_1,\cdots, e_n}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following is an elementary implementation of what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\set}[3]{%
  \{ #1#2{1},
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#3}{3}=0
    #1#2 2
  \else
    \ldots
  \fi
  , #1#2{#3} \}
}

\begin{document}

$\set{a}{^}{3}$

$\set{e}{_}{n}$

\end{document}
```

We condition on what is presented as argument `#3` using `\pdfstrcmp`. `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}` does a string comparison between `<strA>` and `<strB>`, returning `-1` | `0` | `1` if `<strA>` < | = | > `<strB>` (lexicographically).

The only difference between the two sets is the way the second term in the sequence is being set, so those elements are set without consideration of the condition. No consideration is added for `n=1` or `n=2`.

---

A supplementary interface using a single argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\set}[1]{\setaux#1\relax}
\def\setaux#1#2#3\relax{%
  \{ {#1}#2 1,
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#3}{3}=0
    {#1}#2 2
  \else
    \ldots
  \fi
  , {#1}#2{#3} \}
}

\begin{document}

$\set{a^3}$

$\set{e_n}$

$\set{\alpha^{22}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: i would use `\dots` or `\ldots` precisely. Plus may be an auxiliar definition to have easier input `\def\set#1{\setaux#1\relax}` and `\def\setaux#1#2#3\relax{..}` that way one can write `\set{e_3}` or `\set{\alpha^22}` and get all set rather than `\set{\alpha}{^}{22}`.

Comment: Is it possible to define this command just by one input : `\set{\alpha^m}`?

Comment: @C.F.G: I've added that option.

Comment: @Werner: Sorry for comment. My TeXlive 2021 has a few problems with the above code. Your MWE is working very well but in one of my long TeX writings it has problem with `\set` but it is OK with `\sett`. What is the problem?

Comment: @C.F.G: Perhaps you're writing the content to the `.aux`?

Comment: @Werner: I don't understand your comment! you meant I define that macro inside the `.aux` file? No I define it inside the `.tex` file. So why it works for `\sett`?

Comment: What does `\show\set` provide in your `.log` just before defining it? Perhaps `\set` is already defined by another package.

Answer (score 13):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\set}{mmm}
 {
  \lbrace
  \str_case:nnF { #3 }
   {
    {1}{#1#2{1}}
    {2}{#1#2{1},#1#2{2}}
    {3}{#1#2{1},#1#2{2},#1#2{3}}
   }
   { #1#2{1},\dots,#1#2{#3} }
   \rbrace
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\set{a}{^}{3}$

$\set{a}{^}{n}$

$\set{e}{_}{2}$

$\set{e}{_}{k}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative syntax and implementation: the call is `\set[<opt>]{<letter><^|_>}` where `<opt>` is a number or a generic subscript. In case of a number, the sequence is spelt out fully. In the unusual case you want a number, but you prefer the dots, use `[{{9}}]` like in the last example. The mandatory argument has the form `a^` or `a_`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\set}{O{n}m}
 {
  \lbrace
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d+ \Z } { #1 }
   {
    #2{1}
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 2 } { 1 } { #1 }
     {
      ,#2{##1}
     }
   }
   {
    #2{1},\dots,#2{#1}
   }
  \rbrace
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\set[3]{a^}$ $\set{a^}$ $\set[k]{a^}$

$\set[2]{e_}$ $\set[4]{e_}$ $\set[{{9}}]{e_}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses `etoolbox` and `pgffor`. Credits for @TH.'s answer on [Testing for number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/testing-for-number?noredirect=1&lq=1).

This implementation also handles `\mycmd{a}{^}{K}`, where `K` is any positive integer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifnumber[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\temp{#1}%
    \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\temp}
    {\endgroup\@secondoftwo}
    {\expandafter\ifnumber@i\temp\@nnil}%
}
\def\ifnumber@i#1#2\@nnil{%
    \if-#1%
    \ifstrempty{#2}
    {\def\temp{X}}
    {\def\temp{#2}}%
    \else
    \def\temp{#1#2}%
    \fi
    \afterassignment\ifnumhelper
    \count@0\temp\relax\@nnil
    \endgroup
}

\def\numrelax{\relax}%
\def\ifnumhelper#1\@nnil{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\numrelax
    \aftergroup\@firstoftwo
    \else
    \aftergroup\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycmd}[3]{%
        \ifnumber{#3}{%
                \ensuremath{%
                    \foreach \n in {1,...,#3}{#1#2{\n}\ifnum \n < #3 {,} \fi}
            }
        }{%
        \ensuremath{#1#2 1,\ldots,#1#2{#3}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{1}{^}{4}

\mycmd{a}{^}{3}

\mycmd{1}{^}{1}

\mycmd{a}{^}{n}

\mycmd{b}{_}{6}

\mycmd{3}{_}{n}

\end{document}
```

[image]